# windows batch script: copy command issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, xcopy

I've an issue with copy command I'm using in my script. The command syntax is correct (to the best of my knowledge) but this command displays the error of "Path not found"; although the path is present, the file is also present. Not sure what the issue is. My command:

```
if exist D:\CDDATA\LIP\APin.dat* (copy D:\CDDATA\LIP\APin.dat* "D:\CDDATA\LIP\Temp\Apconf.dat") else goto exit12
```

I tried using xcopy instead but it waits for an input while running:

```
Does D:\CDDATA\LIP\Temp\Apconf.dat specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?
```

Tried to suppress it using /C but won't work. Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance,
Adil

Comment: Why the asterisk? I can't save a file with one at the end of the extension. I think it might be treating it as a wildcard if that's not your intention.

Comment: Well, I wondered too on this. But this is how someone else designed the code and I'm struggling to work this out straight. But eventhough I tested locally with & without the asterisk. It works fine on my local system. I tried testing it by removing the asterisk, including the path in quotes, etc. But no solution. Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, next time explain your questions better

```
copy /y D:\CDDATA\LIP\APin.dat D:\CDDATA\LIP\Temp\Apconf.dat
```

Comment: And maybe remove the asterisk, try both ways ;)

Comment: Thank you Davide but I already tried both the options (mentioned above in reply to user1274820). So far, no luck :(

Comment: I mean, I tried both the options in my local system and it's working both with & without quotes. Even with the askterisk I face no issues. Also, in remote & local systems, both the Dos versions are same: 6.1

Comment: Why don't you try this "xcopy D:\CDDATA\LIP\APin.dat D:\CDDATA\LIP\Temp\Apconf.dat\". But you want to copy a file over another file ? Because what you are saying is "Apconfig.dat" is a folder and it isn't, don't you want to copy "Apin.dat" to "D:\CDDATA\LIP\Temp\" ?

Comment: Yep. That seems a problem. I realized the mistake here. The system is considering "Apconfig.dat" as a folder. Thank you Davide for the insight.

Comment: Then what do you want ? To delete "Apconfig.dat" and copy there the "APin.dat" ? Do you just want to copy "APin.dat" to "D:\CDDATA\LIP\Temp\" folder ?

Comment: I want to copy APin.dat in the D:\CDDATA\LIP\Temp\ as Apconf.dat. That's it.

Comment: I've edited my answer try that. I tried on my computer and it worked like this "copy /y C:\bla.txt C:\a\blacopied.txt"

Answer (score 0):

To xcopy to a folder without prompting, end the path with a backslash or use the `/I` switch.

```
"D:\CDDATA\LIP\Temp\Apconf.dat\"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir "D:\CDDATA\LIP\Temp\"
xcopy "D:\CDDATA\LIP\APin.dat" "D:\CDDATA\LIP\Temp\Apconf.dat"/Y/H/v/s
```

Try making the directory FIRST in xcopy THEN copying the files. That works for me.